# What's the best way to protect my rooted Android 7 from malware and hacking?

Tags: privacy, malware, virus

Considering I have to use cellular data and being ***not*** connected to the internet is not an option, what measures can I take or tools I can use to keep myself protected from prying eyes?

My first step will be to do a clean rom flash in case I'm infected already, but as soon as I do that, I'd like to ensure that I remain clean and protected because I would be using my phone for very private data. What can I do? Besides the obvious and common sense stuff of course.

Android 7 | Rooted | Moto C Plus

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer in general because using a known to be insecure device is always a risk. How large the risk is and how to reduce it depends on how you use the device and what apps and use cases are the minimal set you don't want to miss.

Comment: Questions like this are sort of open-ended, in the sense that there is no definitive answer out there. Everyone can suggest this or that thing and claim theirs is the best way. They might not even bother to demonstrate how their solution improves upon existing ones. How would you evaluate them then?